# ubercart - 100% discount on subtotal with shipping fee not passing proper values to paypal

Tags: views, ubercart, payment-gateways

We are running an Ubercart site.

We are generating bulk coupons for 100% value of an sku. On redemption the user is charged for only the shipping fee.

So we need the following passed to paypal

line 1 = subtotal - discount = £0

Line 2 = shipping fee = £3.99

Line 3 = total = £3.99

The problem we have is because the line 1 = subtotal - discount = £0 this is not passing to paypal properly - we can only make it work by combining the subtotal - discount + shipping fee as 1 line however this is causing confusion for the customer as it reads in paypal

Total = £3.99

Shipping = £0

hope you can help